# Xamarin Main.xml is missing from assets then Layout contains malformed xml - Root element is missing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am starting out with Xamarin studio, I have build most basic forms project. In tutorials it shows how to edit layout in `Main.xml`, that is supposed to be in `Resources/layout` that is missing in my solution. So when I add it manually it then fails with error message `The layout contains malformed XML` and another one `Root element is missing`. When I opened the `Main.xml` in notepad I can see contents to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`.

[image]

**How do contents of proper blank Main.xml supposed to be like?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself

Click on source, then add

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">`

and that should do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Review that the markups are start and close correctly; for example,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fondomizzou"  **/>**

NOT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondomizzou" 
**</RelativeLayout> />**
```